# Using Methods in a Defined Time Class

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to define a class Time which takes 3 attributes: hours, minutes, and seconds. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Time:
    '''A class that stores information about time. Attributes: H (int) 
       M (int) S (int)'''


    def __init__(self, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0):
        '''hours represents time in hours, minutes represents time in
           minutes, and seconds represents time in seconds'''
        self.H = hours
        self.M = minutes
        self.S = seconds


    def __str__(self):
        '''Creates a string for appropriate display of time'''
        return str(self.H) + ':' + str(self.M) + ':' + str(self.S)


    def clean(self):
        '''Adjust Time object so that the number of seconds and minutes
           is between 0 and 59'''
        if self.S < 60:
            return
        else:
            self.M = int(self.S/60)+self.M
            self.S = self.S%60
        if self.M < 60:
            return
        else:
            self.H = int(self.M/60)+ self.H
            self.M = self.M%60            
        return self.__str__()


    def to_seconds(self):
        '''Converts Time instance into seconds and returns the resulting
           integer.'''
        minutes = self.H * 60 + self.M
        seconds = minutes * 60 + self.S
        return seconds


    def to_hours(self):
        '''Converts Time instance into hours and returns the resulting
           floating point number.'''
        seconds = self.S * .001
        minutes = self.M * .01
        hours = self.H + minutes + seconds
        return float(hours)


    def addSeconds(self,seconds):
        '''Takes an integer and adds it to the amount of seconds in the
           Time instance'''
        sum_of_seconds = seconds + self.to_seconds
        self.clean(sum_of_seconds)
        return self.__str__()


    def plus(self,hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0):
        '''Takes an extra time object as an arguement and returns a new
           Time object y adding the two Time instances together'''
        time2 = Time(hours,minutes,seconds)
        total_seconds_time1 = self.to_seconds()
        total_seconds_time2 = self.to_seconds()
        total_seconds = total_seconds_time1 + total_seconds_time2
        newtime = total_seconds.clean()
        return newtime
```

I am having trouble with the following:
- I am supposed to use .zfill to format the **str** into HH:MM:SS with leading zeros
- I cannot use my .clean() method in my constructor
- My .plus method returns AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'clean'

Comment: If you have 3 questions, ask 3 different questions, each one with only the relevant part of your code. Please be always clear (your second question is not clear) and say what you have tried, which result you got and whic one you want..

Answer (score 0):

What issue are you having with zfill?  It's pretty simple: `my_string.zfill(2)`, to get a string with at least two characters, padded with leading zeroes if necessary to meet that two-character requirement.

You need to include some examples of why your clean method isn't working.  I will say, though, that your code doesn't do what you think it does.  The `return` statement ends the procedure.  So, if your seconds are less than 60 then the procedure ends and it never checks your minutes.

As for the third question your plus method isn't working because you are trying to call an integer's clean method, which doesn't exist.  `total_seconds` is the result of adding `total_seconds_time1` and `total_seconds_time2`, both of which are integers returned by the `to_seconds` method.

Comment: For the zfill problem, need my return value to look something like this: 02:05:22 instead of 2:5:22

Comment: Try this:  `return str(self.H).zfill(2) + ':' + str(self.M).zfill(2) + ':' + str(self.S).zfill(2)`.  You are coercing each of the integers to a string, so you can call the string's zfill method for each.